# Android ImageReader with MediaProjection: how to remove image extra padding efficiently

Tags: android

Here is how I get image buffer:

```
            image = imageReader?.acquireLatestImage() ?: return

            val planes = image.planes
            val buffer = planes[0].buffer
            val pixelStride = planes[0].pixelStride
            val rowStride = planes[0].rowStride
            val rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * screenWidth

            val realWidth = screenWidth + (rowPadding / pixelStride.toFloat()).toInt()
            val realHeight = screenHeight
```

Why image buffer has extra row padding?
How to convert this buffer to new buffer or bytes[] without row padding efficiently? I need transmit screen images real-time, so efficiency is priority.